# Generated Texture Stretched differently on different objects?

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm using a linked material set to "Generated" vector mapping coordinates on multiple objects, but they are being stretched and squished differently, depending on what objects they're on (see the grungy brick walls in the attached photo)

All of the Scale and other transforms have been applied via the ctrl+A menu, so I dont know what's going on here.

ANy ideas?  Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Use "Object" instead of Generated

Comment: @MikoCG Could you be more specific?

Comment: I would rather use generated.  I posted this question to figure out why its making this error.  If it was working properly, the texure wouldnt be squished, right?  That's the point of generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Generated* texture coordinate means that blender literally generates a bounding box around your object. Think of a cube that gets stretched to fully encompass your mesh. However, blender scales this bounding box the same way as it would be if you scaled a cube in object mode - it results in non-uniform scale for the "box" - this is why the sides that have to be stretched to be more "rectangular" or "elongated" cause the texture to stretch as well.

[image: Gen]

As MikoCG recommended, the best way around this is to use *object* coordinates.
However, while *generated* coordinate places the X/Y origin in the "top left" corner, so to speak, you will have to use a mapping node to get your positioning right (often 0.5 or -0.5 on the X and Y location works fine) when using *object*. Because *object* doesn't generate a bounding box in the same way as *generated*, the textures will behave predictably in every direction.

[image: Obj]

NOTE - these images and description are a crude overview of what's really going on, however, I find it really helps to think this way when picking Texture Coordinates.

Comment: This is great, thank you!